# How to invert Y axis of a ScatterPlotItem in PyQtGraph

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I want to display points in a scatter plot with indices as if it were a matrix, origin top left inverting the Y axis:

```
0,0 1,0
0,1 1,1
```

instead of default where the origin is the lower left.

```
0,1 1,1
0,0 1,0
```

[image]

I tried:

```
plot = pg.ScatterPlotItem(...)
plot.getViewBox().invertY(True) #  view box is NoneType
```

as suggested here [Inverting the Y axis in PyQtGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694752/inverting-the-y-axis-in-pyqtgraph) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the official [doc](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html), when you have data displayed within axes, you end up (directly or indirectly) using a `PlotItem` object as a *container*, as shown in the figure.

[image]

Assuming you are plotting something like the following:

```
plot_widget = PlotWidget()
plot_item = plot_widget.plotItem
plot = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x=[0, 0, 1, 1], y=[0, 1, 0, 1], size=20.0)
plot_widget.addItem(plot) # Or equivalently, plot_item.addItem(plot)
```

You can simply do:

```
plot_item.invertY(True)
```

And here is the result:

[image]